# Hide elements within tabs dynamically in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before I developed a functionality for when you have only one set of tabs. Now the aApp is growing and that tabs functionality is failing since there are more sets of tabs.

The first time the function was like this:

```
var iconTabs = function () {

    $('#icons-tabs a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
    $('.icons-container').hide();
    $('.icons-container:first').show();

    $('#icons-tabs a').click(function(){
        var t = $(this).attr('id');
        if($(this).hasClass('inactive')) {
            $('#icons-tabs a').addClass('inactive');
            $(this).removeClass('inactive');
            $('.icons-container').hide();
            $('#'+ t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
};
```

And the html:

```
<div id="fragment-1" class="fragments text-center">
    <div class="icons-container" id="tab1C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="icons-container" id="tab2C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="fragments-parent">
        <div class="fragments-icons fragments-parent--child">
            <div class="items" id="icons-tabs">
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab1"></a>
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab2"></a>
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab3"></a>
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab4"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the html has a second section and I still have to add 3 more, so now it is like this:

```
<div id="fragment-1" class="fragments text-center">
    <div class="icons-container" id="tab1C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="icons-container" id="tab2C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="fragments-parent">
        <div class="fragments-icons fragments-parent--child">
            <div class="items" id="icons-tabs">
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab1"></a>
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab2"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fragment-2" class="fragments text-center">
    <div class="icons-container" id="tab5C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="icons-container" id="ta62C">
        {{!-- Content --}}
    </div>

    <div class="fragments-parent">
        <div class="fragments-icons fragments-parent--child">
            <div class="items" id="icons-tabs">
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab5"></a>
                <a href="#" class="item" id="tab6"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a JSFiddle in case you want to play:

http://jsfiddle.net/ju3a9zx5/

My mission is to do it dynamic and that every set of tabs has separate behaviour. As you may see in the JSFiddle: the second set of tabs doesn't work, and I want them to have the same behaviour as the first one, but separate, one set of tabs don't have to interfere with the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to want to use classes instead of `id`s to target your tabs. If you see my example below, there are only a few changes:

1. I replaced `id="tabs"` and `id="tabs2"` with `class="tabs"`
2. I changed the event handlers to target the class instead of the ids
3. When finding the related `a` tags I use `siblings()`
4. When finding the related `.container` I use `.nextUntil()` to find the container beneath in the DOM
5. When showing the initial container classes. I use `$('.tabs').next('.container')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.tabs a:not(:first)').addClass('inactive');
  $('.container').hide();
  $('.tabs').next('.container').show();

  $('.tabs a').click(function() {
    var t = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).hasClass('inactive')) { //this is the start of our condition 
      $(this).siblings('a').addClass('inactive');
      $(this).removeClass('inactive');

      $(this).parent().nextUntil(':not(.container)').hide();
      $('#' + t + 'C').fadeIn('slow');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  padding-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabs a {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #5685bc;
  ;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  padding-right: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  display: block;
  background: #FFF;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.tabs a.inactive {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #666666;
  background: #EEE;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a.inactive:hover {
  color: #5685bc;
  outline: none;
}

.container {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-right: solid 1px #CCC;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container h2 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #5685bc;
}

.container p {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: small;
}

.container ul {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 1.4;
  list-style-type: disc;
}

.container li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">

  <a id="tab1">test1</a>
  <a id="tab2">test2</a>
  <a id="tab3">test3</a>
  <a id="tab4">test4</a>

</div>
<div class="container" id="tab1C">1Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab2C">2Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab3C">3Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab4C">4Some content</div>

<div class="tabs">

  <a id="tab5">test1</a>
  <a id="tab6">test2</a>
  <a id="tab7">test3</a>
  <a id="tab8">test4</a>

</div>
<div class="container" id="tab5C">5Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab6C">6Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab7C">7Some content</div>
<div class="container" id="tab8C">8Some content</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, Dave. Did you change something in the css?

Comment: Yeah wherever you had `#tabs` or `#tabs2` I replaced with `.tabs`

Comment: I just realised that when you click on any of the tabs of the first set, the content on the second set disappears.

Comment: I mean, even if you click on any of the tabs of the first set, the second one should maintain its shape.

Comment: @TheUnnamed I changed `nextAll()` to `nextUntil()` to fix that bug. How's it look now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok played around with your fiddle. First remark: change `id="tabs"` to `class="tabs"`, also change the selectors in your javascript and css. With that change it should get you up and running.

From a developer point of view I would create a jQuery plugin and throw the code in an `each()` function to make this even more flexible, better scalable and maintanable.